# How does python evaluate Module execution?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have two files in the same directory one that contains the contents of my program `poker.py` and the other that has test cases `poker_test.py`.

In `poker_test.py` I execute the following commands to run the test cases:

```
import unittest
import poker


class PokerTest(unittest.TestCase):
      (...)
```

Then at the end of `poker.py` while I'm developing i have the following commnands:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #imports Test case and unittest
    from poker_test import *
    unittest.main()
```

Everything works just fine(for now) and this setup is great for iterative development. My question is how does python evaluate `poker.py` when I run it, given that `poker_test.py` depends on `poker.py` and vice versa?

I have a rough idea, but was wondering what the "official" answer is.

Thanks,
-M

Comment: Note that unittest also supports limited commandline arguments: https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface -- In this case, rather than `python poker.py` to run the test, you'd do `python -m unittest poker_test.py` and Bob is your uncle.  you can even run only specific tests.  `python -m unittest poker_test.PokerTest.testSomething`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of whether you should do it, as Alex says, avoid it at all costs.  Cyclical imports are a state of sin.

With that aside, it's interesting to look at what's happening (roughly - it looks like the module import mechanism is [an area that gets tweaked from version to version in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#references).  My main source for this was the Python 3.4.2 docs on the importing system)

When the line within `poker_test.py`:

```
import poker
```

gets executed, the system first checks if the module is already loaded.  Loaded modules live in a dictionary called `sys.modules`.

- If the module being imported is in `sys.modules` already, any reference to `poker` in `poker_test.py` just points to that namespace.  (Note that in the case of cyclical imports, the module might already be added to `sys.modules`, but the populating of the namespace may not be fully over.  Execution of that module might be paused for the moment at the line that says `import this_or_that_other_module`)
- If the module is not there, then the system creates a new namespace, adds it to `sys.modules`, looks for the code that is associated with the `poker` module (in this case, living in `poker.py`) and begins to execute it, putting all the variables in the newly created namespace.

So you'd think `poker.py` gets run once, and `poker_test.py` gets run once and already notices that `poker` is a loaded module, so the importing ends there.  Except...

When a module is run as the original script, it gets registered as `__main__` in `sys.modules`, instead of its actual name.

So `poker.py` is going to be called the `__main__` module, and as a result, when `poker_test` tries running `import poker`, it can't find `poker` under `sys.modules`.  `poker` *will* be loaded twice, once as `__main__` and again as `poker`.  Cyclical imports are frowned upon, but cyclical imports of the `__main__` module is downright condemned because of this issue of creating two identical(ish) namespaces and the potential weird errors that can result.

There are two more complications in your code.

1) `from poker_test import *`

Because you're doing an `import *`, instead of putting all the variables created from `poker_test` in its own namespace, it gets thrown into the `__main__` namespace.

2) `if __name__=='__main__':`

Because you're only importing from `poker_test` if the module is the main script being executed, the Python interpreter will not touch that line when `poker` gets imported from `poker_test`.  So your code isn't really looping conceptually.  `poker` as `__main__` imports `poker_test` which imports `poker` and stops there.  Simple!

...so let's not do circular imports.

Some reference material:

[Official Python 3.4.2 docs on the import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

[2008 comp.lang.python discussion on cyclical imports](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/HYChxtsrhnw)

Answer (score 2):

It's always soundest to avoid circular dependencies like the one you've created here.  However you luck out because the `from poker_test import *` comes at the very end of `poker.py`, i.e, after the latter has defined all it does define, so it can be imported in a good state by the circularly-dependent `poker_test.py`.

However, while this happens to work in current Python version,s it's not guaranteed by the language spec.  For solidity, break the circular dependency, e.g as follows:

- move all the "substantial" contents of `poker.py` before the `if __name__` check to e.g `_poker.py`
- in `poker.py`, just do `from _poker import *`
- in `poker_test.py`, instead of `import poker`, use `import _poker as poker`

This way, your dependency graph becomes acyclical, and as a consequence your code will work as intended in any correct version of Python, including hypothetical future ones:-).